# Unable to reference the InnerException.Message inside Catch(Exception ex)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have the following code as part of my Action method inside my asp.net mvc web application:-

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
      using (var client = new WebClient())
      {

          var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);
          XmlDocument do2c = new XmlDocument();
          query["username"] = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApiUserName"];
          query["password"] = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApiPassword"];
          query["assetType"] = RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
          query["operation"] = "DeleteAsset";
          query["assetName"] = vmj.Resource.RESOURCENAME;
          query["accountName"] = vmj.Customer.NAME;
          query["siteName"] = sitename;
          string apiurl = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApiURL"];
          var url = new UriBuilder(apiurl);
          url.Query = query.ToString();
          try
          {
              string xml = client.DownloadString(url.ToString());
              XmlDocument doc2 = new XmlDocument();
              doc.LoadXml(xml);


          }
          catch (WebException ex2)
          {
              ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Error occurred:" + ex2.InnerException.Message);
          }
          //}
          //}
      }
      ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Error occurred:" + ex.InnerException.Message);
  }
}
```

But when the `Exception ex` occur, i am unable to display its InnerException.Message, and i will get a null reference exception when trying to reference Innerexception.Message. although i have added a brake point and the ex object contains both inner-exception and a message describing the exception. so any idea what is going on ?

Comment: Remove the `try/catch` for the WebException unless you're going to handle it differently.  It will be caught by the outer `try/catch`.  Also, do a check to make sure the inner exception is null before referencing it.  Not all exceptions have an inner exception, I have the feeling you're causing an exception by looking for it that you're not expecting and confusing yourself.

Comment: I am using the WebException since it will return different exception message compared to the outer try/catch. and i check the ex during run time and it have a message an inner exception raised , which indicates that an entity validation error occured.

Comment: does ex2.ToString() contain the text  you need?